# How to read wordpress feeds using robospice?

Tags: android, spring, rss, atom-feed, robospice

I've been studying `robospice-sample-spicelist` in order to adapt part of it for a feed reader I'm trying to code. If I use its `SpringAndroidSpiceService` as-is, I get an exception for not having the right message converter. I realised that the example didn't have anything to do with Atom Feed, so I googled a little and discovered `AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter`. Tried to add it to the list of `HttpMessageConverter` the service uses.

```
public class SevillaDirectoSpringAndroidSpiceService extends SpringAndroidSpiceService {

    @Override
    public CacheManager createCacheManager(Application application) {
        CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager();
        JacksonObjectPersisterFactory jacksonObjectPersisterFactory = new JacksonObjectPersisterFactory(application);
        cacheManager.addPersister(jacksonObjectPersisterFactory);
        return cacheManager;
    }

    @Override
    public RestTemplate createRestTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        // find more complete examples in RoboSpice Motivation app
        // to enable Gzip compression and setting request timeouts.

        // web services support json responses
        MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
        FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
        StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
        AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter atomFeedHttpMessageConverter = new AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter();

        final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> listHttpMessageConverters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();

        listHttpMessageConverters.add(jsonConverter);
        listHttpMessageConverters.add(formHttpMessageConverter);
        listHttpMessageConverters.add(stringHttpMessageConverter);
        listHttpMessageConverters.add(atomFeedHttpMessageConverter);// here I get an error marker on eclipse with the following message
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(listHttpMessageConverters);
        return restTemplate;
    }

}
```

But when I do, I get this error message:

> **The type com.google.code.rome.android.repackaged.com.sun.syndication.feed.atom.Feed
>   cannot  be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class
>   files**

I've tried every jar found in the `robospice-sample-ui-spicelist`. I've tried to build `robospice-sample-google-http-client` using Maven, but it doesn't seem to have a "libs-for-ant" where I can find the jars it depends on.

Googling for "robospice" and "feed" or "atom feed" gives little to no help.

Comment: Have you imported this library? https://code.google.com/p/android-rome-feed-reader/

Comment: I guessed it would be in the robospice dependencies. This part of the error message is the one intriguing me: " It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"
Doesn't it mean that it's referenced in the jar dependencies i got from robospice samples?

Comment: No it is a spring-android dependency, needed for parsing rss and atom.  It is not bundled with Robospice.

Comment: But a pull request to include such a library (using rome for instance) would be welcomed.